# Using header value as table name in Camel sql component

Tags: sql, apache-camel

I would like to use the header value for setting the name of db table in sql component. Is there an easy way to do this?
.to("sql:drop table ${in.header.tablename}")
throws invalid character exception

Answer (score 1):

If you want to route the message dynamically, you can use [recipient-list](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html). The route could be

```
from("direct:a").recipientList(simple("sql:drop table ${in.header.tablename}")).
```

Comment: Yes use a dynamic-to as this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: Thanks. I was able to resolve this with .recipientList and adding a .end() after that as I am using the sql component within .choice blocks

Comment: Great, this works (though I left out "in." in parameter name).

Answer (score 0):

The point of using the sql component instead of the jdbc one is that the former allows you to use the message payload as parameters to the query.

For what you want, just use named parameters to access the headers from the query. There is an example right in the [sql component docs](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html) :

```
from("direct:projects")
    .setHeader("lic", constant("ASF"))
    .setHeader("min", constant(123))
    .to("sql:select * from projects where license = :#lic and id > :#min order by id")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I set the header value for the table name using another header .setHeader("tablename", simple("XYZ_${header.controlnum}",String.class)), but when I access it in sql .to("sql: drop table :#controlnum"), I get a ORA-00903: invalid table name exception

Comment: My fault. I realize now the solution is not valid since what you want to do is a drop table, so no place for named parameters. Now, wouldn't [jdbc component](http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html) be a better fit for you? You could build your sql into the message body with simple and forward it to the jdbc component.

Comment: Documentation is nice, only it does not work at all (at least not as is described in documentation). I have table name either in body (in java.util.Map [HashMap instance] as it is written in documentation) and in header, but it is never filled into sql component query (camel 2.14.1). I just want to do simple select, where table is named parameter.